# Getters and setters as methods, vs getters and setters as properties in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, getter-setter

If my understanding is correct, properties are used for getters and setters. Decorating a getter or setter with `@property` allows us to modify it, use it, etc, as if it were an attribute, so rather than doing something like `MyClass.foo()`, you would do `MyClass.foo`. I've read that this is done in order to keep your code more clean and improve readability. Is there any other reason to use decorate getters and setters with `@property`? I've read somewhere that it is better to use properties to also not break you code when wanting to make a change, which I don't understand why you would need properties for that when you have getter and setter methods that are not properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [article](https://realpython.com/python-property/) you linked to in the comment says:

> The main advantage of Python properties is that they allow you to
> *expose your attributes* as part of your public API. If you ever need to
> change the underlying implementation, then you can turn the attribute
> into a property at any time without much pain.

The keywords here are to "expose your attributes".

Say you have a class `Object` with an instance attribute `weight`, which you initially expose as part of the API and allow end users to freely modify:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 0
```

But you later discover that some end users are setting `weight` with negative values, which should be considered invalid:

```
o = Object()
o.weight = -1
```

So you modify your class by adding a getter and a setter method and renaming the original attribute with a `_` prefix in order to hide it:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        self._weight = 0

    def get_weight(self):
        return self._weight

    def set_weight(self, value):
        assert value >= 0 # validate that weight is not negative
        self._weight = value
```

But then you need make changes to your exposed API and tell the end users to make corresponding changes on their end:

```
o = Object()
o.set_weight(-1) # now this will be properly disallowed and raise an exception
```

which is troublesome for both you (having to change your exposed API documentation) and your end users (having to change the way they use your API).

Now, by converting the `weight` attribute to a property instead:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        self._weight = 0

    @property
    def weight(self):
        return self._weight

    @weight.setter
    def weight(self, value):
        assert value >= 0 # validate that weight is not negative
        self._weight = value
```

The end user can continue to use their existing codes:

```
o = Object()
o.weight = -1 # raises an exception
```

and they now get the benefit of having a proper validation to `weight`, without ever needing to know that the underlying implementation has changed from an attribute to a setter method.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, `@property` is similar to getter/setter, but it behaves a little different when calling.

When using normal getter/setter, for example:

```py
class Foo:
    def getFoo():
        # ...
    def setFoo(foo):
        # ...

my_foo = Foo()
# print foo value
print(my_foo.getFoo())

# set foo to 100
my_foo.setFoo(100)
```

As you can see, that's kinda ugly. So Python has the `@property` decorator to solve this:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_foo = 1

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self.inner_foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self.inner_foo = value

foo = Foo()
print(foo.foo)
foo.foo = 100
print(foo.foo)
```

Now the `foo` property acts like a normal property when usage and makes you code much more cleaner.

Comment: I've heard they are also better to use if wanting to later make changes to your getter or setter, why? Like if we were to use getters and setters and not decorate them with `@property`, then we would break our program when wanting to make a change to them however if we'd use properties, then our program would be fine.

Comment: @DavidKolesanov That would be the case if you wasn't using getter/setter the first time when you write your code. For example, you might first write as a normal property but later on you want to do something when fetching/setting the property, and used getter/setter methods to achieve that. In this case, you need to change all references to that variable to your getter/setter methods.

Comment: @DavidKolesanov no, that isn't true. The whole point of `property` is so you **don't have to write getters and setters at all**. Property is for when you need to manage access *after*, so you can change that behavior without breaking the API

Comment: @DavidKolesanov note, the example of `property` above shouldn't be written in the first place - the getters and setters *don't do anything* so it should just be regular attributes